# CSS conflict media queries in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've a page where I use firefox specific css using `@-moz-document url-prefix()`.

The thing is I have a media query targeting ipad resolutions. I've used firefox specific codes in the media query too. But firefox 10 doesn't pick this css and only pick the normal css. for an example.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.with-hotel-list{
    margin-right: 5px !important;
    width: 130px;
}
.search-form input[type="button"]{
    margin-left: 57px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 810px) and (min-width: 765px) {
   .search-form input[type=button] {
      width: 118px;
      margin-left: 36px;
    }

    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .hotel-list{
        height: 33px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .search-form input[type="button"] {
        margin-left: 46px !important;
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
}
}
```

Can any one help me on this. do I need to put the browser specific css first?

Comment: Why are you still supporting Firefox 10? It's not a version that pre-dates the rapid release cycle, so it shouldn't have stayed relevant for very long.

Comment: this is a requirement of my client so I have to support firefox 10

Comment: I think its a firefox internal bug for ff10. For ff9 media queries were working fine https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/918036